# Excel IF Condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

In Excel, how would I perform the following using the `IF` condition?

- If cell is empty then set the background color to red.
- If cell has a value then set the background color to green.

Comment: To change the background color of a cell, you would use [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx), rather than trying to use the IF() function in a cell formula.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply a regular red fill, then use conditional formatting to make it green if populated, e.g. in conditional formatting use the

"use a formula to determine which cells to format" option with the formula

`=A1<>""`

assumes formatting applied to cell A1, change as appropriate. For a range of cells just write the formula for the top left cell, e.g. to format B3:J10 this way select that range and use

`=B3<>""`

Comment: Alternately, set both rules in Conditional Formatting.  For a rule to apply if empty, use something like `=A1=""`.  Another nice thing about Conditional Formatting, is that it can be set for one rule to apply to multiple (and non-adjacent) cells.